# apns-collapse-id does not replace push notification

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm using libcurl on my server side PHP script to send PHP notifications via HTTP/2.  In my headers I'm sending an `apns-collapse-id`, like so:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [  
    'apns-topic: ' . BUNDLE_ID,  
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . generateAuthenticationHeader(),  
    'apns-collapse-id', 'qwer1235'  
]);  

$url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{$url}");
```

When the notification comes in I don't acknowledge it on the phone, and then I send another message with a different alert title but the exact same `apns-collapse-id`.  Both messages are then displayed on the phone.  My understanding of the `apns-collapse-id` is that it should have removed the older message and replaced it with this new one.

Am I missing something?